# drawText on a lower right position

Tags: android, eclipse, drawtext

how can I draw a text in the lower right of the screen?

heres my code on drawtext.
**EDIT**

```
Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    if(this != null) {
        timeCounter.start();
        int time= timeCounter.getTimeSeconds();
        String timetxt= String.format("%02d:%02d", time/60, time%60);
        timer.getTextBounds(timetxt, 0, text.length(), textBounds);
        canvas.drawText(timetxt, -textBounds.left, -textBounds.top, timer);
        }
```

I just follow some tutorials but it doesn't work. can someone help me on this logic? thanks in advance !

Comment: You need it via canvas only or you can work with RelativeLayout as well ?

Comment: see Paint.getTextBounds method

Comment: i already set up getTextBounds sir @pskink but my problem now in on drawtext parameters.

Comment: why do you measure *text* but draw *timetxt*?

Comment: the text appears on the upper left of the screen. how can I possibly locate it on the lower right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope you are trying to do this within a views ondraw callback.

if so, 2 things you might want to consider.

- use simpleDateFormat instead of formatting the string by yourself. its much easier.
- you are drawing outside of your view.

sind upper left corner is 0,0 any value for textbounds.left or textbounds.right > 0 would at least partially hide your text.

if you want this to be drawn at the lower right corner you need to call this:

```
canvas.drawText(timetxt, this.getWidth()-textBounds.left, this.getHeight()-textBounds.top, timer);
```

if you are not doing this in a onDrawCallback, move it into one ;)

Comment: is doesn't work either. I cant even see the timer now sir @DanielBo

Comment: you were able to see the timer before? can you please post more code, because that seems weird

Comment: it should be this.getWidth()-textBounds.right and this.getHeight()-textBounds.bottom

Comment: oh, yeah sorry. my bad. but you got what i meant :)